# Laravel Data truncated for column 'id' at row 1 Error

Tags: php, sql, database, laravel, phpmyadmin

I'm to execute this command but it show data truncated error although all columns have sufficient length for the values enter.

[image]

Comment: https://laracasts.com/discuss/channels/laravel/data-truncated-when-trying-to-create-personal-access-client-for-passport

Comment: thank you for the discussion that helped me solve the issue.